# ng-show not recognizing boolean?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using ng-show to display a log in and log out screen, I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing incorrectly here. im defining mc.show as an object in myController. setting the boolean to true initially, then changing the value based on if there is a user or not. but something isn't working here.

js file_

```
var firebase = require('firebase'),
    angular = require('angular'),
    angularfire = require('angularfire'),
    config = {
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyD8Q0uYpB4hpWg16-xxw31B0YP7aUoj9fc',
        authDomain: 'testone-1849f.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://testone-1849f.firebaseio.com',
        storageBucket: 'testone-1849f.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: '139803200782'
    };


firebase.initializeApp(config);

angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
       .controller('myController', myController);

function myController($firebaseObject) {
    var btnGoogleIn = document.querySelector('#btnGoogleIn'),
        btnGoogleOut = document.querySelector('#btnGoogleOut'),
        mc = this;

    mc.show = {
        boolean: true
    };

btnGoogleIn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  //console.log("logging in");

    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);

    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()
    .then(function (result) {
        var user, token;
        if (result.credentials) {
            token = result.credential.accessToken;
        }
        user = result.user;

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // var errorCode = error.code,
        //     errorMessage = error.message,
        //     email = error.email,
        //     credential = error.credential;
    });
});

btnGoogleOut.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    firebase.auth().signOut()
    .then(function () {

    },function (error) {

    });
});


 //add a real time listener
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (firebaseUser) {
        if(firebaseUser) {
            mc.show.boolean = false;
            console.log('logged in');
            console.log(mc.show.boolean);
        }
        else{
            mc.show.boolean = true;
            console.log('not logged in');
            console.log(mc.show.boolean);
        }
    });
```

*html file*

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController as mc" >
    <div id="login" ng-show="mc.show.boolean">
        <input id="btnGoogleIn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Log in with Google"/>
    </div>

    <div id="logout" ng-show="!mc.show.boolean">
        <input id="btnGoogleOut" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Log Out"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where do you define mc.show? Are you getting any JS errors in the browser?

Comment: here is the rest of my js file....

Comment: I'm not sure that edit was successful. I don't see the file.

Comment: not getting any errors

Comment: ok, i can see it now.

Comment: Can you confirm that console.log functions in onAuthStateChanged are firing correctly? Can you also confirm that you are able to access the scope from the html template (i.e., `mc.foo = "bar"` in your JS is successfully interpolated when you place `{{bar}}` in your template) ?

Comment: the console.log functions do output a value to the console. logged in and false. nothing is successfully interpolated however, this was another issue that I am working on, still learning how to implement angularfire fully and correctly.

Comment: Ok, so take it back a step. You need to get interpolation working. Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/v5krEd2PeAwTbNPOOw9k?p=preview) and see if it provides any clues.